# How can I solve ESLint parser issues related to Liquid template language in JavaScript and CSS inside HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, eslint, liquid

I am using a HTML code with JavaScript and the Liquid template language by Shopify inside `<script>` tags. I also have ESLint installed in the project. ESLint gives a **Parsing error** due to the Liquid syntax. I wanted to know if there is a plugin or parser that I can install to include the Liquid syntax (or ignore it). I have come across several possible solutions but they are not valid for my use case. I have highlighted some of them.

- I don't want to disable linting for the whole file, as the other ESLint rules are valuable for the JavaScript code within the `<script>` tag
- I cannot use Visual Studio Code (or other editor) settings as I am working as part of a team which uses different editors.
- There are some suggestions to use an ESLint preprocessor to ignore some syntax, but I would prefer a simpler off-the-shell solution due to time/complexity
- This is a parser error, not an ESLint rule that can be disabled

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am struggling with the same thing.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no. That project is on hold at the moment.